# SQL Joins to Get Monthly Total Wages from Three Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get `empolyees` info from `employees table`, and their total wages from two different tables.

The SQL is approximately like this, but I don't really know how to use joins to do this:

- `CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) from employees as e`
- `Sum(hours*pay) where date is "THIS MONTH" and employee_id = e.id from taxed_work`
- `Sum(hours*pay) where date is "THIS MONTH" and employee_id = e.id from nontaxed_work`

I am not sure how to join these together properly. I don't want to see any of the employees that have not done either kind of work for the month, only those who have. I'm using mysql and will put the data in a table with php

If anyone could tell me how to do the "THIS MONTH" part that would be cool too. Just being lazy on that part, but figured while I was here...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you give us the database structure of the 3 tables and "example" data  for each?

Comment: employees id-int, first_name-varchar, last_name-varchar;
taxed_work id-int, employee_id-int, date-date, hours-float(8.2), pay-float(8,2); nontaxed_work identical to tax_work

Comment: the work tables save the hours and pay for each employee who works on any given day that they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use correlated subqueries:

```
select  concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)
,       (
        select  sum(hours*pay)
        from    taxed_work tw
        where   tw.employee_id = e.id
                and year(tw.date) = year(now())
                and month(tw.date) = month(now())
        )
,       (
        select  sum(hours*pay)
        from    nontaxed_work ntw
        where   ntw.employee_id = e.id
                and year(ntw.date) = year(now())
                and month(ntw.date) = month(now())
        )
from    employees e
```

Comment: I tried that before and it through an error, but I'll see if it was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: It's telling me I have an syntax error near "from taxed_work tw where..."

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate their totals inside subquery.

```
SELECT  a.id ,
        CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) FullName,
        b.totalTax,
        c.totalNonTax,
FROM    employees a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT employee_id, Sum(hours*pay) totalTax
            FROM taxed_work
            WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%c') = DATE_FORMAT(GETDATE(),'%c')
            GROUP BY employee_id
        )  b ON b.employee_id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT employee_id, Sum(hours*pay) totalTax
            FROM nontaxed_work
            WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%c') = DATE_FORMAT(GETDATE(),'%c')
            GROUP BY employee_id
        ) c ON c.employee_id = a.id
```

Comment: This would repeat each row in nontaxed_work for each row in taxed_work. This results in double-counting and far too large results

Comment: @Andomar you're correct. much better if it can be done inside subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
select 
    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as employee_name,
    sum(case when t.this_date = 'this_month' then t.hours*t.pay else 0 end), 
    sum(case when n.this_date = 'this_month' then t.hours*t.pay else 0 end) 
from employees e 
    left join taxed_work t on e.id = t.employee_id
    left join nontaxed_work n on e.id = n.employee_id
group by (first_name, ' ', last_name)
```

Please replace the t.this_date and n.this_date fields with actual field names as I am not aware of the exact table structure. Also, replace the "this_month" value as per your need.

Comment: This would repeat each row in nontaxed_work for each row in taxed_work. This results in double-counting and far too large results.